# How to read the colorspace being used in an image

Tags: c#, jpeg, color-space

How, in C#, can I define the colorspace a JPG is in? I am trying to create a small app to automatically convert to sRGB any image submitted in AdobeRGB colorspace.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the content of this question helpful.

It seems to relate to the problem you are having.

[Converting JPEG colorspace (Adobe RGB to sRGB) on Windows (.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174832/converting-jpeg-colorspace-adobe-rgb-to-srgb-on-windows-net)

If you are running a server side component to this application, then making a call to the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) convert command would be a very easy option.

Comment: Daniel, before running the conversion, I want to make sure the image is actually in the wrong colorspace. I know how to convert, I just need to find out if the image does indeed need to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

I've approached this problem on OSX by shelling out to [sips](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) and examining the result:

```
sips -g space /your/imagePath/here.jpg | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

I compare the second return value to "CMYK" to determine whether I need to convert to RGB.

Not useful if you're on a different OS, though.